# Виртуальные страницы WordPress-плагина - как их создавать?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-плагины

Стандартный подход к реализации страниц плагина на сайте в WordPress заключается в создании страницы с shortcode-кодом внутри и использованием в плагине add_shortcode( ), а можно как-то без создания реальной страницы?

Чтобы плагин как-то создавал собственные виртуальные страницы по определенным URL-адресам?

К примеру, я хочу чтобы по адресу: [http://сайт/regform](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/regform) мой плагин выводил бы нужный мне контент.

Answer (score 0):

Все можно. Вставьте такой код в function.php:

```
function dynamic_page() {
    $uri  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $scheme = $_SERVER['HTTPS'];
    }
    else {
        $scheme = '';
    }
    if (($scheme) && ('off' !== $scheme)) {
        $scheme = 'https';
    }
    else {
        $scheme = 'http';
    }

    if ( '/dynamic/' === $path ) {
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
            Это моя динамическая страница
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'dynamic_page' );
```

Таких if с проверкой адреса на сайте, например, `/dynamic/`, может быть сколько угодно.

Результат работы тестового примера можно посмотреть [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/dynamic/).